# Transferir datos de una DB Sql Server local a una DB en un servidor remoto cada cierto tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos local que recibe datos de ventas, inventario, facturas y demás durante el día. En un server remoto tengo otra base de datos SQL Server que necesito que reciba los datos que entran a la base de datos local, en general solo necesito transferir los datos de 4 tablas cada cierto tiempo (digamos cada 10 minutos) el problema es que estas tablas tienen mucha información así que preferiría que solo se enviara lo nuevo y lo demás lo ignorara, use el Export Wizard de SQL Management Studio pero es algo bastante lento según lo intente, quisiera saber si hay una manera mas practica de conseguir esto.

Comment: Para eso deberás usar Publications y Subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un job de SQL Agent para programar tareas periódicas de transferencia de datos con paquetes de integración SSIS

Answer (score 1):

Yo creería que hay que ver el ámbito de enlace. Si están linkeadas las base de datos puedes usar el comando MERGE de sql para agregar solo los que faltan e ignorar el resto. De no tener conexión alguna apoyo lo de JFuentes usar un paquete SSIS con una tarea de envío remoto de tus índices existentes para solicitar los nuevos y una segunda de traer los datos faltantes

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar de varias formas:
El que me resultó práctico fue la herramienta **Tablediff de SQL Server**, desde línea de comandos que compara tablas y genera el script para ejecutarlo en el servidor destino.
Luego puedes automatizar el script para ejecutarlo cada 01minuto, 10minutos o de acuerdo al requerimiento mediante el Agente de SQlServer o mediante las tareas de Windows.

**Para ello se requiere:**

- Conectividad a nivel de base de datos entre los servidores origen y
  destino.
- Usuario_sql (datareader) en servidor origen.
- Usuario_sql (escritura) en el servidor destino.

**Otras Alternativas:**

1. Implementación de un trigger en la tabla desde el servidor origen
   para reflejar las operaciones DML en el servidor
   destino.(Configuración en el Servidor Origen).
2. Utilizando la herramienta de desarrollo SQL Server Data Tools(Visual Studio)
   mediante DACPAC (Configuración en Servidor Destino).
3. Utilizando el SSMS.